# javascript submit action not working in ie8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

There are two forms on my document
I have four action buttons on my form on FORM2
Each button provides a different form.action
The target of the action are PHP scripts

The buttons work on chrome/firefox
On IE8 I get the error `'object doesn't support property or method'`

I've tried the following

As button `type='button'`:

```
document.getElementById('searchform').action = "index.php?p=advancedChart";
document.getElementById('searchform').submit();

document.searchform.action = "includes/download.php";
document.searchform.submit();
```

As button `type=submit`:

```
document.forms['searchform'].action='includes/download.php'
this.form.action='includes/download.php'
this.forms['searchform'].action='includes/download.php'
```

Comment: Why not just (uniquely) name the buttons, make them all *submit* types and detect which was pressed (by name) in the PHP script?

Comment: Could you post your entire page so we can see the forms?

Comment: @Phil—because then there would be no (client side) script involved. ;-)

Comment: sorry to ask, but how do I add such a large block to the thread.

Comment: `CTRL-C + CTRL-V`  or go to www.jsfiddle.com, post it in the appropriate areas and then hit `Save` and give us the URL of the saved code

Comment: Are any of your form attributes set to: type="hidden" name="action" if so, you need to change the name.